# 7.1.0.431 prism unity forms will not build on UWP

Tags: xamarin.forms, unity-container, prism

Today's new Prism.Unity.Forms installs 2 new dlls that produce 2 errors:

Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'Unity.Abstractions.dll'. Source files: 
C:\Users\xxx.nuget\packages\unity\5.8.11\lib\netstandard2.0\Unity.Abstractions.dll
C:\Users\xxx.nuget\packages\unity.abstractions\3.3.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Unity.Abstractions.dll

and

Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'Unity.Container.dll'. Source files: 
C:\Users\xxx.nuget\packages\unity\5.8.11\lib\netstandard2.0\Unity.Container.dll
C:\Users\xxx.nuget\packages\unity.container\5.8.11\lib\netstandard2.0\Unity.Container.dll

No such errors in previous version.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to read the release notes when upgrading. Depending on where you upgraded from you may encounter breaks.

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/releases/tag/v7.1.0

As you will see in the release notes We target a different package than we used to. This was unavoidable as the Unity 5 package is quite different and the Unity NuGet was breaking apps. You are encountering the issue because you have the new Unity.Container reference from Prism 7.1, and a direct reference to the old Unity NuGet. Uninstalling the Unity package will fix your issue.